# How does PIE *d- in *dlegh- change to PGmc. p- in plegō (E pledge)?

Tags: etymology, sound-change

As shown in the Wiktionary:

***[pledge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pledge#Etymology)***

> From Middle English plege, from Anglo-Norman plege, from Old French plege (Modern French pleige) from Medieval Latin plevium, plebium, from Medieval Latin plebire "to pledge", from Frankish *plegan (“to pledge, support, guarantee”), from Proto-Germanic ***plegō** (“responsibility, habit”), from Proto-Indo-European ***dlegh-**.
>
> Akin to Old High German pflegan (“to take care of, be accustomed to”), Old Saxon plegan (“to vouch for”), Old English plēon (“to risk, endanger”). More at plight.

But I can't find the clue to this sound change on Wikipedia, which concludes that only PIE *b will become PGmc. p-.

PS: AHD contains the same etymon ***[dlegh](http://www.google.ru/books?id=4IHbQgz1nZYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN#v=onepage&q=dlegh&f=false)***

Comment: I haven't found anywhere online other than Wiktionary that attempts to trace it back beyond **plegan** so this may be somebody's off-the-wall theory (I wish Wiktionary put an emphasis on sources, as Wikipedia does). Pokorny does not have the word in any of its indices, but it does have a root **dhlgh** (with **dh* not *d*) with the right meaning: most of the cognates quoted are Celtic, but there is Gothic _dulgs_ and a couple of Slavic examples. Nothing with _p-_ though.

Comment: @ColinFine Hi! In fact American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Root contains the same etymon, see the edited source please~

Comment: FWIW, the AHD of IE Roots (your link) says "Germanic *plegan, probably altered (by dissimilation) from *tlegan."

Comment: @AlexB. Oh, please forgive my humble attention of the context in my link. So the answer is that it's not a regular sound change?

Comment: I don't really know. So it would seem, at least based on the AHD.

Answer (score 4):

To beging with, English word *pledge* is a loanword from Old French (attested in English since 14th c.), see [here](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=pledge).

However, the French word is itself a Germanic loanword, coming from a West Germanic **plegan*, see [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/PLEIGE).

The natural outcome of this West Germanic root in English is *play*, see [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=play) (this semantic change is less surprising if you remember that when you make a **pledge** you effectively get in the **game**). The connection of this West Germanic stem to the IE root **dhl̥gh-* ‘debt’ (e.g. [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=play)) is only an *ad hoc* hypothesis going against the general correspondences (German /p/ goes back to IE /b/, not /dh/).

Pokorny's *IE Etymological Dictionary* does not mention any German continuant of this root (see [here](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fpokorny&text_number=%20419&root=config)). And even within the Germanic group it seems limited to the West subgroup, see [here](https://www.dwds.de/wb/pflegen).

Therefore, the etymon of English *pledge* must be considered unknown (cf. Orel's *Handbook of Germanic Etymology*, p. 292).